# How to get another field value based on the raw value in a droplink field?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I'm working on a part of a sitecore site and I'm still getting used to how to code for it. I'm more familiar with using SQL to select, insert, delete, and update things, so I a probably making this issue much more difficult than it truly is.

Basically, what I have is a droplink field in the sitecore database called, "Complete Product Name." This is linked to another field called "Complete Name," which is the one I want to get the value for (So, I want to do a search for the "Complete Name" field using the "Complete Product Field" value).

```
 Item CPNItem = db.Items[orderItem.Fields["Complete Product Name"].Value];
 if (CPNItem != null)
 {

     //find complete name field on CPNItem

 }
```

I can get the "Complete Product Name" value just fine, but it's not what I want....I'm so used to using SQL to do searches like this that I'm really confused on how to proceed.

Any help would be great! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is use something like the following:

```
Item CPNItem = db.GetItem(orderItem["Complete Product Name"]);
if (CPNItem != null)
{
    //find complete name field on CPNItem
    var name = CPNItem["Complete Name"];
}
```

Of course, that's assuming `db` is in fact an instance of the `Sitecore.Data.Database`. You don't have to use the `.Fields["fieldname"].Value`, as that could result in a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: db is an instance of Sitecore.Data.Database, yes. I will try this suggestion and see how it works.

Comment: Ok, I tried it out and it worked! Thanks a lot! I was making it much more difficult than it needed to be...